# DoubleValidator is not checking the ranges properly

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5.4

Let me use an example to explain the issue.

If we have a `TextField` like this,

```
TextField {
    text: "0.0"
    validator: DoubleValidator { bottom: -359.9;
        top: 359.9;
        decimals: 1;
        notation: DoubleValidator.StandardNotation }

    onEditingFinished: {
        console.log("I'm here!");
    }                    
}
```

We can type numbers such as `444.9`, `399.9` or `-555.5`. As you can see, the values are not between `-359.9` and `359.9`.

In the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-doublevalidator.html#details) we can find the following information:

> Input is accepted but invalid if it contains a double that is
>   outside the range or is in the wrong format; e.g. with too many digits
>   after the decimal point or is empty.

I thought `DoubleValidator` didn't accept this kind of things, but unfortunately it does.

So I suppose the solution would be to check the final input, but again we have a problem: `editingFinished` is only emitted if the validator returns an acceptable state and this is not always the case.

Perhaps I'm not doing a good approach, I'm not understanding how to use `DoubleValidator` or maybe I need some code in C++.

By the way, I'm working with Qt 5.4.

Comment: The double validator prevents invalid values to be accepted when enter is pressed. Is that not what you want?

Comment: @xsquared Actually, if I type 500 the `TextField` shows that value and if I press enter or change to another `TextField` in the window, the data is not cleared. Do you have a little example to test what you said?

Comment: I checked the documentation again and indeed found the problem.  Please read my answer below, I hope that it helps you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that [QML TextField](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html#validator-prop) accepts *intermediate* input:

> **validator : Validator**
>
> Allows you to set a validator on the TextField. When a validator is set, the TextField **will** only **accept input which leaves the text property in an intermediate state**. The accepted signal will only be sent if the text is in an acceptable state when enter is pressed.

The [`validate()`-function of QDoubleValidator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html#validate) describes when it returns `QValidator::Intermediate`:

> **State QValidator::validate(QString & input, int & pos) const**
>
> This virtual function returns Invalid if input is invalid according to this validator's rules, **Intermediate if it is likely that a little more editing will make the input acceptable (e.g. the user types "4" into a widget which accepts integers between 10 and 99)**, and Acceptable if the input is valid.

So that means, the validator returns `QValidator::Intermediate`, as long as a double value is entered and because TextField is okay with "intermediate", you can type anything as long as it is a number.

What you can do is to subclass `QDoubleValidator` and to override `validate()`, so that it does not return `Intermediate` when the values are out of bounds:

```
class TextFieldDoubleValidator : public QDoubleValidator {
public:
    TextFieldDoubleValidator (QObject * parent = 0) : QDoubleValidator(parent) {}
    TextFieldDoubleValidator (double bottom, double top, int decimals, QObject * parent) :
    QDoubleValidator(bottom, top, decimals, parent) {}

    QValidator::State validate(QString & s, int & pos) const {
        if (s.isEmpty() || (s.startsWith("-") && s.length() == 1)) {
            // allow empty field or standalone minus sign
            return QValidator::Intermediate;
        }
        // check length of decimal places
        QChar point = locale().decimalPoint();
        if(s.indexOf(point) != -1) {
            int lengthDecimals = s.length() - s.indexOf(point) - 1;
            if (lengthDecimals > decimals()) {
                return QValidator::Invalid;
            }
        }
        // check range of value
        bool isNumber;
        double value = locale().toDouble(s, &isNumber);
        if (isNumber && bottom() <= value && value <= top()) {
            return QValidator::Acceptable;
        }
        return QValidator::Invalid;
    }

};
```

Comment: Very good answer! However I ran into a few problems problems which I'd like to share. `MyValidator` should be `TextFieldDoubleValidator ` and `return QValidator::Invalid;` is outside the function `validate`. I need to integrate this new component into my QML application but I had some compilation errors. To solve them, I had to add a new constructor `TextFieldDoubleValidator (QObject * parent = 0) : QDoubleValidator(parent) {}`. Please, give me your opinion on all this.

Comment: Ah thank you I integrated your corrections, they are all valid.

Comment: Any idea why out-of-bounds input is a valid as an intermediate state for `DoubleValidator` but *not* for `IntValidator`?

Comment: The documentation says otherwise. What exactly is your out-of-bounds value and what’s your range?

Comment: @x Sorry, didn't see your comment, and I have forgotten the exact cases. I think it even permitted '-' for positive numbers, though, and '9' for values between 5 and 7.

Comment: @KyleStrand, "Any idea why out-of-bounds..." First of all, it is not true (at least in Qt6) you can type, f.e., 3000000000 (which is greater than 2^31 - 1). Second of all, this is because look at the following: you have a double validator set to your input with, say, maximum of `100.0`, then you typed `1000`, this is intermediate because you can type `0.` in front of it. More over, you can type `e-6` at the end (provided you have scientific notation).

Answer (score 4):

I found an easier way.

```
TextField {
    id: control
    onTextChanged:
    {
        if(!acceptableInput)
            control.undo()
    }
}
```

When text in TextField is invalid, acceptableInput would change to false, so when text changed ,check the property, if it's false, then call undo() to undo the changes.

Comment: IDK if it's only me but the behaviour is annoying. You can't even clear the input, for example.

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by @xsquared was perfect. I think it's a good idea to share with anyone curious how to integrate the solution with `QML`.

`TextFieldDoubleValidator` is the class which @xsquared suggested.

So the first thing is to register the new type in our main.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQml>
#include "textfielddoublevalidator.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<TextFieldDoubleValidator>("TextFieldDoubleValidator", 1,0,
                                              "TextFieldDoubleValidator");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

After that, we can use the new type in our `QML` application:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import TextFieldDoubleValidator 1.0

Window {
    visible: true

    // DoubleValidator doesn't clear the TextField when
    // text > 359.9 or < -359.9
    TextField {
        text: "0.0"
        validator: DoubleValidator {
            bottom: -359.9;
            top: 359.9;
            decimals: 1;
            notation: DoubleValidator.StandardNotation
        }
    }

    // Solution: use your own DoubleValidator.
    // This works OK and text is cleared out when
    // text > 359.9 or < -359.9
    TextField {
        y: 50
        text: "0.0"
        validator: TextFieldDoubleValidator {
            bottom: -359.9;
            top: 359.9;
            decimals: 1;
            notation: DoubleValidator.StandardNotation
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pure qml version:

```
TextFieldInput{
validator: DoubleValidator
{
    bottom: minimumValue
    top: maximumValue
}

property real maximumValue: constants._MAXIMUM_INTEGER
property real minimumValue: constants._MINIMUM_INTEGER
property string previousText: ""

onTextChanged:
{
    var numericValue = getValue()
    if (numericValue > maximumValue || numericValue < minimumValue)
    {
        text = previousText
    }
    previousText = text
}

function setValue(_value)
{
    text = String(_value)
}

function getValue()
{
    return Number(text)
}}
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think there are 2 mistakes in above code. 1) `TextFieldInput` is not a valid QML component. 2) You never used the `setValue()` function. BTW when I changed these 2 things the code worked like a charm. Thanks a ton for that!! :)